# c# read SQL Table (with special characters) into DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datatable

I am having an issue reading special characters from SQL Datatable and loading into a datatable in C#. I'm currently using SqlDataAdapter to fill my table:

```
using (oSQLConnection = new SqlConnection(oDBConnection.ConnectionString))
{
    oSQLConnection.Open();
    using (oSQLDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sQuery, oSQLConnection))
    {
        oSQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        oSQLDataAdapter.Fill(DataSource, sTableName);
    }
}
```

But this does not work well for special characters such as `Sam’s` notice the quote it's not a normal quote. Also characters like `rest – now` is not a normal en dash (- it's an em dash) for this example the character will show up as `rest ¿ now` in the dataset. One of the member said try using SqlDataReader but DataSet doesn't have a load function (only DataTable) - Do you guys have any other suggestions?

I found that these results are coming out like this if i put a breakpoint in the code after this method is called. In the dataset it'll show up as `rest  now` and if i were to export this dataset into a csv file it comes off with the `rest ¿ now`. My guess is that the character is not supported in the dataset so it converts into another character that is supported by dataset.

SQL Column dataType = nvarchar

Thanks.

EDITED:
Okay guys so i figured out why these characters are NOT matching. It is because we load the DATA into Oracle with em dash or the special quotation mark. However Oracle does NOT support these characters so they switch the character with another character that is supported the upsidedown question mark. I believe it's because Oracle is in UTF8 and we retrieve the data in SQL (ie. do the string matching in SQL) Since SQL has variable coming in as upside down question mark They do NOT match.

So i have a question for you guys. When we load these special characters in Oracle - EM Dash and special quotation . is it possible to keep the character the same? so when we retrieve it in SQL it comes up as accordingly

Thanks.

Comment: What are you looking at that you think it's not displaying properly? A dataset doesn't display things; so you're looking at a debugger, or string output, or html, or something. Whatever that something is might not support unicode. Can you give more details? The text in the CSV file, how are you saving that? Many plain text editors encode a way that would not support that character set.

Comment: Here is a link that might help you, specific to CSV encoding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728282/unicode-in-csv-file

Comment: @Nikki9696 Thanks for your help!! I have updated the question .. this is why the string did not match . Let me know if you have a solution to this new question

Comment: Hm... been some time, but when I used to work in Oracle, I needed to load numerous Charsets (including cyrillic and arabic). I think you will need to use something like the "UNISTR" command when reasing from the Oracle source and afterwards perform the corresponding reconversion when loading to SQL.

Comment: Well, I don't do Oracle, but I did find this. Maybe it will help? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm

Comment: Great Thanks a lot guys for all the help!! it's just a matter of changing the character type in Oracle :)

Comment: @civic.sir Before you go changing the character type in Oracle, please read this article.  There are issues you need to be aware of beforehand.  Doing so blindly can potentially cause some major issues.  Things like data truncation can occur for example.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, but it's untested so bear that in mind!

I came across a similar issue some time ago with special characters in Oracle.  We have our character set to UTF-16.  Had wierd things like umlauts and other ascii characters outside the normal 32-127 range.

One thing you might try is first doing an HTML encode to anything outside that range, loading that into your datatable in c#, then as the datatable is filling (or after it's been filled...), perform an html decode on those fields.

We have an html encode function that does this for us, like so:

```
  FUNCTION HTML_Encode_Special_Characters
   (p_string IN VARCHAR2,
    p_do_encode IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'Y')
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    first_location number := REGEXP_INSTR(p_string, '([^' || CHR(1) || '-' || CHR(127) || '])');
    v_string VARCHAR2(32000);
    v_char VARCHAR2(1 char);
    v_ascii_number number;
  BEGIN
    IF p_do_encode = 'Y' AND first_location > 0 THEN
      v_string := p_string;

      FOR i IN first_location .. length(v_string) LOOP
        v_char := substr(v_string,i,1);
        v_ascii_number := ascii(v_char);
        IF v_ascii_number > 128 THEN
          -- just replace all of them
          v_string := REPLACE (v_string, v_char,'&#' || v_ascii_number || ';');
        END IF;
      END LOOP;

      RETURN (v_string);
    ELSE
      RETURN p_string;
    END IF;

  END;
```

So this should load "string" data into your table and any case where you have special characters, it would show up like '&#189' or something to that effect.

Then on the C# side you could do something with html decode:

```
using System.Web;

HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(mystring);
```

Again... untested.  But it should be very easy to implement and test out and/or tweak it slightly to get it working.

An alternate solution would also be to simply perform a datafix on your database to change all those special characters to "regular" representations (ie, an em-dash to a normal dash).  You can do that with some regular expressions, using the CHR() function, and to view odd data using the DUMP() function.